# Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address) with the same id "0" already exist

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, login, register

I am trying to debug this error which happens whenever i try to register or login.

```
Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(576): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address))
#1 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(522): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(538): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->getAddressesCollection()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(566): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->_getAddressByType('shipping')
#5 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1400): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->getShippingAddress()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php(234): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->getTotals()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Abstract.php(179): Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar->getTotalsCache()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php(91): Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Abstract->getTotals()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/design/frontend/default/shisha/template/page/html/cart.phtml(49): Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar->getSubtotal()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('top_cart', true)
#16 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/design/frontend/default/shisha/template/page/html/header.phtml(53): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('top_cart')
#17 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#18 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#19 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#23 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/design/frontend/default/shisha/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#24 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#25 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#26 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(115): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#31 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->indexAction()
#32 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#33 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /var/www/vhosts/hitechsoft.eu/httpdocs/demosite/shishavillage/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}
```

I'm not sure what is causing the error. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the thing is there were some constraints missing in my Database. After adding those constraints, it worked like a charm.